# Is there a fallacy

Tags: fallacies

I want to know if there is a fallacy in this type of conversation.

**CA=Country A** and  **HRA=Human Right Association**

Example:

**CA:** it is now gonna be forbidden in CA for feminist to express their feminism and if we catch one she will pass 2 months in jail.

**HRA:** You can't do that because you are violating their human right of expressing themselves.

**CA:** The HRA is not the one leading our Country we got representative carrying about those types of question and in the name of what should feminist have the Right to express themselves ?

**Note** that in this context feminists are not a threat to the society or institution of Country A.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I do not think there is any fallacy in the conversation, simply because I see the point of either party, and I do not see any error in reasoning or *ad hominem*. It is not even an argumentation (in the logical and philosophical sense).

Comment: This is less of a fallacy and more of a clash of values. HRA is talking about human rights (let's say, it comes with some justification, and not just a say-so), the challenge is not to the point made but rather to the source of its authority, along the lines of "who are you to tell us how to run our country". This could be an *ad hominem*, in a personal debate, *if* CA just uses it to deflect a point it knows to be valid. But it could equally be an objection to a question begging definition of human rights that appeals to a moral authority it does not recognize.

Comment: There is a suppressed premise in the response of HRA that societies all subscribe to Enlightenment governmental principles.  Non-signatories to international agreements are not bound by them, and not all basic approaches to government accept modern assumptions of democratic liberalism.  This is one of the internal contradictions of these principles: imposing them requires violating the rights of people who never accepted them.  Multicultural liberalism itself requires that if a people chooses another path explicitly enough, that is their right.